# Laravel group by on model hierarchy

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've searched this about two days in the site but was unable to find a similar example.
I'm trying to code the equivalent of this Oracle command in Eloquent:

```
select  d.code, d.grp, d.cname, sum(d.poso1)
from    pers_data e, misth_master m, misth_detail d
where   e.per_emploeeno = m.emp_no
and     m.misaa = d.misaa
and     e.per_emploeeno = '04004'
and     m.year = '2019'
group   by d.code, d.grp, d.cname;
```

It basically joins 3 models in hierarchical fashion ( e -(has_many)-> m -(has_many)-> d), applies constraints on 1st and 2nd and groups/sums data from the 3rd.
The result set is smt like this:

```
CODE    GRP     CNAME   SUM(POSO1)
----    ---     -----   ----------
153     1       cname1  0
2       0       cname2  3480
2       1       ..      1003,2
162     1       ..      250,8
        5       ..      2464,67
30      4       ..      172,68
102     1       ..      949,08
105     1       ..      37,5
111     1       ..      25
0       0       ..      21600
11      1       cnamen  3976,26
```

In Laravel, I've declared the relevant models (e=Employee with relationships to m=misthoi and d=details).
After many experiments, I've come to this lines of code to achieve this:
(*Please note that Employee model has a global scope and thus needs not be constrained in this piece of code, i.e. e.per_emploeeno = '04004' is implied*)

```
$mdata_flat = Employee::with(['misthoi' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('year', '2019');
        }, 'misthoi.details'])->first()->misthoi->pluck('details')->flatten();

$mdata_grouped = $mdata_flat->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item['grp'].'.'.$item['code'];
})->map(function ($item) {
        return [$item->max('cname'), $item->sum('poso1')];
    })->toArray();
```

It works, indeed, but seems to me complicated and I'm fan of simple, readable code.
I'm convinced there is a neat way to do this with Eloquent.
Could it be written in simpler manner?

It could be generalized as:

Let **A, B, C** be 3 hierarchical related models (A->B->C).
I want to group data of **C** *only*, based on constraints on **A** and **B**.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I actually think that might be the cleanest way. Technicaly Eloquent doesn’t have a group by, you’re just using the DB query builder class at this point, so what you’ve done is probably the best you’ll get for your complexity of database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't 100% understand the Oracle syntax, but it looks like [joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) to me.

I would "translate" it to Laravel's query builder as:

```
DB::table('pers_data')
 ->join('misth_master', 'pers_data.per_emploeeno', '=', 'misth_master.emp_no')
 ->join('misth_detail', 'misth_master.misaa', '=', 'misth_detail.misaa')
 ->where('pers_data.per_emploeeno', '=', '04004')
 ->where('misth_master.year', '=', '2019')
 ->select(DB::raw('SUM(misth_detail.poso1) as total'))
 ->groupBy('misth_detail.code', 'misth_detail.grp', 'misth_detail.cname')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's joins alright, a very simple case of group by / sum of a bunch of tables. But I'm trying to do it with the ORM methods ("..equivalent.. in Eloquent"), not the query builder. I think the purpose of declaring the models and their relationships as classes/methods is that you don't have to directly query the DB tables anymore and also make your app independent of the DB vendor. I thought it would be straightforward using the model relationships, but obviously it's not...

Comment: Ok, I thought you didn't know how to do it using the query builder because you were using collections in your question which is much less performant than doing it in the database. 

Eloquent doesn't support aggregations by related models yet.